# Downsampling and then upsampling signal changes the original length

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

Disclaimer: I am sure that the answer is on the internet. All I want is someone to direct me to the correct reference. Thank you in advance!

I am studying autoencoders and specifically [this example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/autoencoder#define_a_convolutional_autoencoder). In that particular example we denoise a `28x28` image. We do this by downsampling it **2 times**, using a **stride of 2**. The encoder outputs a `(7, 7, 7)` array (height, width, number_of_filters_applied). The problem occurs if we tried to downsample one more time using, again, a stride of 2. Since it cannot output an array of `(3.5, 3.5, 7)` (suppose we use 7 as the number of filters) because 3.5 is not a valid number of elements, the output would be `(4, 4, 7)`. If we tried to upsample this signal the length would be `4x4` -> `8x8` -> `16x16` -> `32x32` which is different from the original `28x28`. Since not always the length of the signal is going to be a multiple of `2^n`, where `n` is the number of times we downsample/upsample, how can we effectively take care of the changes in the size of the signal? My goal is to upsample a downsampled signal to the original size in order to compare the *prediction* with the actual clean data. If the size is different, I cannot compare them.

Comment: One possible approach: pad the input to a size that is exactly divisible by the number of downsamples you have in the network and store the original size. Do the down & upsampling, when calculating the loss zero-out the loss coming from the padding area.

Comment: Ok! that'll do! Thanks a lot!